# Метрики программного обеспечения

Tags: метрики

Какие средства существуют и имеют практическое применение для определения метрики программного обеспечения. Спасибо :-)

UPD. Интересно услышать про свободно распространяемый инструментарий для Java/C/C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант: svn+fisheye(jira) - красивые картинки [здесь](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/tour/code-analysis.jsp). На мой взгляд jira и ей подобные тулы это правильное место для метрик. UPD:) Jira бесплатна для некоммерческого использования. Да и вообще некоторые утверждают, что джира это для бедных. Я себе покупал стартер по $10 за компоненту. Всего-то 2100р за 7 компонент))). Кстати, насчет "для бедных": в нашей компнии заказывали специальных людей, специалистов по джире, чтоб они за деньги растачивали джиру под нужды предприятия, а это уже явно не "для бедных".

С точки зрения расчета бабла, предсказания стоимости трудозатрат на разработку ПО мне, например, больше всего нравится подходы типа [Анализа функциональных единиц](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_point_analysis)(FPA). На тему функциональных единиц интересно почитать роман Томи ДеМарко [deadline](http://lib.aldebaran.ru/author/demarko_tom/demarko_tom_deadline_roman_ob_upravlenii_proektami/). Товарищи типа [Макконела](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/3159814/) говорят, что неплохо работает [COCOMO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COCOMO) для расчета бабла, на практике не пробовал. Есть еще далеко не бесплатная UML среда [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/), которая помимо красивых картинок умеет расчитывать COCOMO уж не знаю насколько адекватно, по-видимому в зависимости от адекватности автора модели)), но возможность такая там есть. Если к этому прибавить возможность reverse engineering исходников для кучи языков, то может все получиться с расчетом. Единственное, не уверен насчет работы с продуктом в фазе maintenance, вроде интеграции с svn по коду исходников у нее не было. Кстати лучше этой среды про UML ничего не видел. State-of-the-art как говорится.

Да и для правильного расчета бабла таких статических моделей как FPA и COCOMO не достаточно, чтоб приблизится к цели надо еще учитывать каким образом группа разработчиков будет дробить задачу и как будет параллелить подзадачи между собой, для этого обычно используют всякие диаграммы Ганта или [PERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Evaluation_and_Review_Technique) сети. От этого конкретного варианта распараллеливания работ будет завить время сдачи проекта и сопутствующие суммы бабла.

Вот, с виду не плохой мануал на эту тему: [как считать бабло](http://enel.ucalgary.ca/People/Smith/619.94/prev689/1997.94/reports/farshad.htm).

Неправильное, но интересное для программиста(возможно) место для метрик это в среде разработки. Самое правильное  место для этого в среде разработки - это всякие встроенные в среду тулы для рефакторинга.  Мне, например, одно время очень нравилась возможность плагина [Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) к студии считать метрики для каждой функции в файле и выводить рядом с первой строкой функции эту самую метрику. Если схлопнуть все функции очень легко было найти плохие функции, - те у которых метрика высока. Наиболее полезными, простыми и понятными кажутся [СтрокКода](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Количество_строк_кода) и [Цикломатическая](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Цикломатическая_сложность) метрика.